# Am I using boolean values in the wrong place? Console output does not appear

Tags: c#

I have a 4-line poem. I read this poem line by line from the text, flip the sentence over and assign it to the array. The purpose of my inversion is to find the rhymes at the end of the poem. In my code I try to find the word ryhme. For example - Lifting her arms to soap hair
"She wrings the water from her hair. Here is the word rhyme hair. I put the hair in the array by letter by letter. But when I want to show it on the console, the output does not appear. Where do I go wrong?" //

```
      string[] ss2 = new string[reversed.Length-1];
        bool flagword = false;
        
        int sayac = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < linenum - 1; i++) //word
        {
            int k = 0;
            while (reversed[i].Substring(k, 1) == reversed[i + 1].Substring(k, 1))
            {
                ss2[i] += reversed[i].Substring(k, 1);
                k++;
                flagword = true;
            }
            if (reversed[i].Substring(k, 1) == " ") sayac++;
        }
        if (flagword && sayac != 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ss2[1]);
        }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint and step through your code line by line

Comment: What I am _guessing_ is, that you have an off index by one : `i < linenum - 1;`. Should be `i < linenum;` But all this is really hard to read. Maybe consider breaking it down into different functions, that you can test individually.

Comment: That part is correct. I am confused with booleans, I cannot understand their exact usage.

Comment: @Fildor There are 2 hard problems in programming: cache invalidation, naming, and off-by-one errors

Comment: Ah, I saw it. Yes, the border is ok. But your output isn't. Given that line 1 and 2 rhyme on the same word and line 3 and 4 rhyme on the same word, ss2[1] will be null.

Comment: But anyway: why all the fuzz? Split the lines by word boundaries, take only the last entry per line, then see if words are equal ...

Comment: Kind of off topic on the programming side, but, you know just repeating a word isn't really rhyme, right? And even checking the ends of words rather than full words won't help you; huge amounts of rhyming words have the same sound spelled differently, like "wear" and "hair".